# Ubuntu blinking underscore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, grubrescue, reinstall

I had Ubuntu installed in Dualboot with Windows 8.1 but I don't know how I deleted the 2 OSes so now it's stuck in Grub Rescue. Now I am trying to install Ubuntu but when I boot to my USB it shows a blinking underscore and it does nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to take out the drive and completely wipe in from another PC before installing another os, I believe I had this problem before and a complete wipe fixed my issue.

Comment: I dont have any other computer :( Is there a way to wipe the disk from grub rescue?

Comment: No, I am afraid not. You may also try other things such as troubleshooting in your bios for problems. Check to make sure you have secure boot turned off.

Comment: Hmm i will check everything such as try whit another os or verify if ubuntu is flashed right and then i will check bios

Comment: Once my computer work again i will do that